# JavaFX: Fill a percentage of a circle with arc

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

I want to fill a certain percentage of a green circle with gray color. I'm trying to get the gray arc to take 60% of the circle, however it doesn't work:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleArc  extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage applicationStage) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        Circle circle = new Circle(100);
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        Arc arc = new Arc(0, 0, 100, 100,
                -360 * 0.6, Math.toDegrees(0.6 * Math.PI));
        arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        arc.setFill(Color.GRAY);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(circle);
        group.getChildren().add(arc);

        flowPane.getChildren().add(group);

        scrollPane.setContent(flowPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);
        applicationStage.setScene(scene);
        applicationStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @VGR The gray area on the picture is not 60% of the circle

Comment: A full circumference is 2π radians.  You are multiplying 0.6 times half the circumference, so the arc is 30% of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Correct way:

```
double rate = 0.6;
Arc arc = new Arc(0, 0, 100, 100,
                0, -360*rate);
arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
arc.setFill(Color.GRAY);
```

Thus gray is 60% of the circle and green 40%.

[image]

Comment: Reading the code I can see you switched from using radians (incorrectly, as pointed out by VGR) to degrees. You're also using `360` degrees (which is 2π radians) instead of π radians. But your answer would be greatly improved if you _explained_ that is what you changed along with why that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Slaw I don't know why it fixes the problem. I just tried different values and this one worked.

Comment: Before you were doing `Math.toDegrees(0.6 * Math.PI)`. But `π` radians is **half** a circle, so you created an arc that only covers 60% of **half** a circle—also known as 30% of the full circle. You changed the math to `0.6 * -360`. Now you're working in degrees, not radians, and `360` degrees makes a full circle. The negative changes the direction of the arc (clockwise instead of counterclockwise, I believe).